# Create Azure table storage folders

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a worker role running that creates tables in table storage, and I would like to be able to group these tables into categories like you would under a folder.

I cannot see any way to do this with the table classes in .Net, but when I look in my table storage 'Tables', I see a 'Metrics Table' entry which looks like a 'folder' and expands to show multiple metrics tables below it.

How can I create/add one of these myself programmatically?

Any ideas gratefully received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is that you can't. Table Storage Service contains tables and then each table contains entities. The functionality about `Metrics Table` you're talking about is a UI feature where the UI combines all these tables together.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is not possible. Metric tables are handled differently by Visual Studio. They are not even returned when using `Query Tables` storage REST API (you can only use them directly by name). Tools like Azure Storage Explorer do not show them at all.

Back to your question. Best practice is to use common prefix for tables in same 'category'.

ex. `WAD*` for all azure diagnostics tables, `NLog*`for nlog tables.